# Custom page 404 jsp does not pick up css

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a custom page 404 jsp page that works fine but does not pick up the css (and image).

My directory structure:

```
 -webapp
 - -error
 - - -jsp
 - - - -page404.jsp
 - - -styles
 - - - -style.css
```

I have tried the following but still got no result(don't want to do embedded css because it is not only the css that I need to reference in my JSP)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
```

and a few more...

Any advice?

Comment: would it be `/error/styles/style.css`?

Comment: Tried that too, does not work.

Comment: Found out the answer: "../error/styles/style.css" Thanks anyway.